# 'conda list' does not recognized by cmd on windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, anaconda

I have installed anaconda on Windows 10 pc from [Official Anaconda Page](https://conda.io) and installed it. But after that I testing the installation in cmd and it shows that

'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

But Spyder Jupiter Notebook are added on my Recently added app list.

[My CMD screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CbQE.png)

Comment: You have to use the Anaconda Prompt

Comment: Thank you @darthbith but my windows search cannot find anaconda prompt. I've found it in the recently added list. Still I cannot find anaconda prompt by searching.